# Conditional mutating with regex in dplyr using rowSum

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following df

```
test = read.table(text = "total_score_1 total_score_2 partner_total_score_1 total_score_3 total_score_4 letter
                  1 -1 1 1 -1 B
                  1 1 1 -1 1 C
                  -1 -1 -1 -1 1 A", header = T)
```

I'd like to match all columns that contain "total_score" but NOT the word "partner" and then create a new measure that sums across all "total_score" columns, treating the -1 as 0.

I'm able to take a basic rowSum like so

```
mutate(net_correct = rowSums(select(., grep("total_score", names(.))))
```

Note, however, this does not exclude the possibility of matching the word "partner", which I wasn't able to find out how to do within a single `grep` command.

However, I'd now like to create a `total_correct` value which is a rowSum on the same columns except the -1s are treated as 0s.

This would result in a data.frame like so:

```
  total_score_1 total_score_2 partner_total_score_1 total_score_3 total_score_4 letter total_sum
1             1            -1                     1             1            -1      B         2
2             1             1                     1            -1             1      C         3
3            -1            -1                    -1            -1             1      A         1
```

One way might be to just count the total number of "1s" (rather than actually doing a sum), but I could not figure out how to do so within a mutate command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
test %>% 
mutate(net_correct = select(.,setdiff(contains("total_score"), contains("partner"))) %>%  replace(., . == -1, 0) %>%  rowSums())

#  total_score_1 total_score_2 partner_total_score_1 total_score_3 total_score_4 letter net_correct
#1             1            -1                     1             1            -1      B           2
#2             1             1                     1            -1             1      C           3
#3            -1            -1                    -1            -1             1      A           1
```

Comment: Woah.  News to me that you can have pipes within pipes.  That's amazing

Answer (score 1):

You could simply modify your regex to capture only columns that *start with* 'total_score' using the caret character:

```
mutate(net_correct = rowSums(select(., grep("^total_score", names(.)))))
```

To treat the negative numbers as zero, you can use `mutate_all()`:

```
test %>%
  mutate(total_correct = rowSums(select(., grep("^total_score", names(.))) %>% 
                                 mutate_all(function(x){as.numeric(x>0)})
                              )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think you missed the more important part of the question which is to create  a `total_sum` variable in which the negative values are treated as 0s.  Also in my actual df there are random prefixes in front of "total_score", so that grep won't actually do the trick  In the past, I was using something like `index <- grepl("total_score", names(data)) & !grepl('partner', names(data))` but it was clumsy

Comment: I updated it relative to your test data. You need mutate_all. For selecting the right columns, the strategy really depends on the structure of your data - if you have a few columns, it might be least hassle just to select them with a range - either to positively select the correct columns or to remove the partner columns, e.g. using `select(.,-c(3,6))`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility could be:

```
test %>%
 mutate(net_correct = rowSums(select(., contains("total"), -contains("partner")) %>% 
                               replace(., . == -1, 0)))

  total_score_1 total_score_2 partner_total_score_1 total_score_3 total_score_4
1             1            -1                     1             1            -1
2             1             1                     1            -1             1
3            -1            -1                    -1            -1             1
  letter net_correct
1      B           2
2      C           3
3      A           1
```